# Shared Preferences leading to multiple activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I am checking whether the user has "logged in" using SharedPreferences by using it inside onCreate. I tried doing it inside onStart too. But the problem is that after "ProductCategories" is visible to the user, when I click back button of the mobile screen I can see multiple ProductCategories activities have been opened. I keep on clicking back button a few times then I get the very first activity "MainActivity".

```
package com.example.pager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedPreferences != null) {
        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("logged", false)) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ProductCategories.class));

        }
    } else {


        finish();
    }
}

public void register(View v) {
     Intent i = new Intent(this,Signupdetails.class);
     startActivity(i);

}

}
```

ProductCatedories.java doesn't contain anything as it has to show a fragment named HomePage.class which i have mentioned in ProductCategories' xml file. I am posting the HomePage's code now:

package com.example.pager;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class HomePage extends Fragment {
    public HomePage(){}
    String[] listitems;
    int[] images = {R.drawable.cadburysilk,R.drawable.cadburys_dairymilk,R.drawable.perk,
            R.drawable.kitkat,R.drawable.nestlemunchchocolate,R.drawable.cadbury_bournville_bar,
            R.drawable.snickers};
    ListView list;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home_page, container, false);
        Resources res = getResources();
        listitems=res.getStringArray(R.array.items);
        list = (ListView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.itemslist);
        AdapterClass adapterClass = new AdapterClass(HomePage.this.getActivity(), listitems, images);
        list.setAdapter(adapterClass);
        return rootview;
    }
}

class AdapterClass extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    Context context;
    int[] images;
    String[] names;
    public AdapterClass(Context c, String[] items,int imgs[] ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(c, R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.quantity, items );
        this.context = c;
        this.images = imgs;
        this.names = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.img);
        TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
        textView.setText(names[position]);
        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: show `ProductCategories` code

Comment: @AntonKovalyov Here's the code^. Please see.

Comment: Why didn't you show `ProductCategories` activity code?

Answer (score 0):

you can change the ProductCategories Definition task in manifest to singleTask:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ProductCategories"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

Comment: It didn't do anything.

Comment: how MainActivity launched? is it defined as android.intent.category.LAUNCHER? add Log to onStart()  inside MainActivity to see how many time it called

Comment: also log `ProductCategories` activity